# 2 seconds of darkness

Tags: electrical, wiring, circuit-breaker, fire-safety

I got a 240 plug in room a, running 4 1000 watt lights.

I got a table lamp in a 110 in room b

When the 240 kicks on in room a, the light i have pluged into the 110 goes off for a second or 2 in room B, actually the rest of the house, then they're back on, without any breakers tripping. These are obviously different circuts, why is this happening, and is it dangerous?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. What are you using 4kW of light for? What kind of lamps are in the 110 socket? Are you in the US? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: That may be thermal, but it's definitely bad. You or someone needs to review the wiring on this circuit ASAP.  The four 1000W lights are actually too much for a 240V/20A circuit, which can only support 3840VA of lighting. You need to look at your lights and get the VA figure.  A sodium, mercury or halide light can be 1300-1400VA each.

Comment: Thank you, the lights are for a hydroponic set up, the lamp is just a table lamp with an led bulb in it (60 watt equivilant). Yes im in th US, in northern California. And yes I will take that tour, sorry if I broke any protocalls. I just googled a question, and luckly ended up here, I love the way this forum is set up. Also I believe the 240 is on a double pole breaker, if that makes any sense. I had a friend set it up, hes a contractor. Doesn't make him right though, ill look into it. Thanks guys.

Comment: @Harper - Reinstate Monica: That should be an answer.

Comment: _"I love the way this forum is set up"_ -- please do take the tour. It's important to understand this site is not a user forum in the usual sense, and treating it that way will result in low-quality posts and experience.